# How to redirect pages to 404?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

How to redirect a page ?

```
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6</a>
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=8 </a>
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=69 </a>
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=61 </a>
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=62 </a>
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=63 </a>
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=64 </a>
<a href="famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=6">famaglam.com/?option=com_category&id=65 </a>
```

These all pages will be redirect to 404 error page.
It showing on google hidden pages so it will create problem in SEO

Comment: you can have change permalink ? so changes this url to valid url.

Comment: yeah i changed already.. its not showing pages in wordpress admin panel.. some URL's are coming and i do not know from where they are coming and they are redirecting to homepage.  i want to redirect 404 error page...

Comment: use 404 redirect plugin for your this list urls

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?option=com_category&id=(6|8|6[123459]) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: its not working ... please open the link http://www.famaglam.com/?option=com_category1&id=6 

its so many page these type of url its redirect to home page but i want to 404 error page

Comment: Make sure this rule is **first rule** in your .htaccess

Comment: this is my .htaccess file
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?option=com_category&id=$1) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

</IfModule>

Comment: In this .htaccess insert my suggested rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following meta tag to the pages that you want to redirect.

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0"; URL="http://www.famaglam.com/404error.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

use the header function:

```
header('location: /404.php');
```